# Use One-Hot encoding for few categories for one row

Tags: python, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I have categorical dataset like this:

| Name | Color (Category) |
| --- | --- |
| Car | Red |
| Grass | Green |
| Sky | Blue |
| Apple | Red,Green |
| Photo | Black,White |

So one row can have **one or few** categories.

Also I'm using OneHotEncoder for categories:

```
data = asarray([['red'], ['green'], ['blue']])
print(data)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
onehot = encoder.fit_transform(data)
print(onehot)
```

The output will be

```py
[['red']
 ['green']
 ['blue']]
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Is it possible to use OneHotEncoding for two or more categories?

Like `Red,Green` convert to `[0. 1. 1.]`?

I'm reading *OneHotEncoder* and *tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical* documentation and can't find such solution.

#### Another solution

I met opinion somewhere, that I need to change my logic to this:

| Name | Color (Category) (Remove) | Red | Green | Blue | Black | White |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | //Red | True | False | False | False | False |
| Grass | //Green | False | True | False | False | False |
| Sky | //Blue | False | False | True | False | False |
| Apple | //Red,Green | True | True | False | False | False |
| Photo | //Black,White | False | False | False | True | True |

So just ignore **Color** column and make few outputs for Sequential model.

But isn't it exactly the same as converting `Red,Green` to `[0. 1. 1.]` ?

I'm feeling that I miss something obvious, sorry if my question is dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it is better to use `MultiLabelBinarizer` from `sklearn`. If `df` is a dataframe with the data of your dataset, you can do something like that :

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit_transform(df["Color (Category)"].str.split(","))
```

Link to sklearn documentation : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html

Answer (score 1):

One hot encoding name is coming from single high bit and the others are low. So if you encode it as 011 it is not one hot encoding anymore.
There is a binary encoding approach, but in that case, if you encode randomly like this

```
001 blue
010 red
011 green
100 blue red
```

Then it will be problematic for this scenario because red and green will share the second bit and they will affect each other whole training process.

So in order to arrange these sharing bits for contributing to the learning, the table you showed is a logical approach for this problem as below

```
    001 blue
    010 red
    100 green
    110 green red
    111 green blue red
```